# CSS image row equal height that fills width and preserves aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 3 images with different aspect ratios to display in a row that fills the container width. I want their heights to be equal but fluid. So images preserve their aspect ratio but scale to fit the width of the container.

Here's my attempt:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/creativetags/pen/ExXmjGV)

```
.row
  display: flex
.wrap
  padding: 0 20px
img
  object-fit: cover
  max-width: 100%
  height: 100%
```

It isn't currently preserving the aspect ratio but they do resize and fill the container width.

Ideal solution wouldn't need Javascript

Comment: CSS cannot do this, you need JS to retrieve ratios then calculate which width (%) should be each to be same height and fill the row .`object-fit: cover` is the best you can have here. If ratios are known, see `aspect-ratio` if that helps.

Comment: object-fit: cover should be preserving aspect ratio (ie not distorting the image) but it will crop at the sides (or top/bottom) as needed to get them to fit. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: Do you know the aspect ratios of the images in advance?

Comment: @AHaworth I do know aspect ratio in advance in this case. Probably best to hard code it rather than use Javascript in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with based on knowing the aspect ratios in advance:

https://codepen.io/creativetags/pen/eYRRGzj

```
.row
  display: flex
img
  max-width: 100%
  height: 100vw / ((900 / 400) + (300 / 300) + (400 / 300))
```

Feel free to contribute any more generalised solutions

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "padding: 0 20px" from ".wrap" to get the images cover the three divs. Is that what you need?

Comment: that deserves to be a comment ;)

Comment: Right:) But could be the solution.

Comment: I do not think so, padding is there to show different background colors of the div ... it's on purpose ;)

Comment: The gap was intentional